# How to make a remote connection to a MySQL Database Server?

Tags: mysql, connection

I am trying to connect to a MySQL database server (remote), but I can't. I am using an user with grant privileges (not root user). The error message is the following:

Can't obtain database list from the server.
Access denied for user 'myuser'@'mypcname' (using password: YES)

"myuser" is an user I created with grant access. This user allows me to connect locally to every database. I am using the same software versions in both hosts: MySQL Server 4.1 (server) and EMS SQL Manager 2005 for MySQL, edition 3.7.0.1 (client).

The point is that I need to connect to the remote server using a different user, not root user. So, how to make the connection?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You have to make sure that the remote user account matches what the server will see coming in for a connection. For instance:

```
grant select on dbname.* to myname@mypc;
```

will not work if `mypc` is not resolvable on the server via DNS or the hosts file. In this case, you could try either using an IP, or a FQDN:

```
grant select on dbname.* to myname@10.1.2.3;
grant select on dbname.* to myname@mypc.example.com;
```

Answer (score 0):

Look in [connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/) to see if you have the right connection string used for [MySql](http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure

- that your MySQL server listens not only on localhost
- your user can access the server from his location. Try 'myuser'@'%' in the GRANT command.

Answer (score 0):

```
 //EMS manager for mysql
 //this magnificient tool provide you with a way to connect to such a server that prevents access to the server from any remote file or any way from outside world
 //all you need is to have ftp access to the remote server
 //in c:/program files/Ems/  you will find file called emsproxy.php
 //it is what we call An (API) in programming world
 //upload that file to your remote server
 //then when you connect with EMS you select tunnling -->checkbox
 //it will ask you on the next step to provide a full url of your emsproxy.php
 //i tested that process myself. i did not have access to cpanel nieghter phpmyadmin
 //thanks
```